# Graph API error 503 serviceNotAvailable when getting item from SharePoint site in Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API in Power Automate where I make calls out to perform some actions.  I have been successful with all Graph calls up to this one where I get a 503 serviceNotAvailable error.

The call I am trying is below

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/b40e54ac-5626-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/drive/root:/filepath.docx
```

If I paste this directly into Graph Explorer on the Graph API site it works fine so I am happy that the call is syntactically correct.

I can't get the call to work through Power Automate.  I also have tried this through Postman and am getting the same 503 error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "serviceNotAvailable",
    "message": "The service is not available. Try the request again after a delay. There may be a Retry-After header.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "87725851-77fb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2020-03-01T16:55:43"
    }
  }
}
```

Permissions in my app registration are

- Directory.AccessAsUser.All
- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Files.Read.All
- Files.ReadWrite.All
- Group.Create
- Group.Read.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- Group.Selected
- Sites.FullControl.All
- Sites.Manage.All
- Sites.Read.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All
- TeamsActivity.Read.All
- TeamsActivity.Send
- TeamsApp.Read.All
- TeamsApp.ReadWrite.All
- TeamsTab.Create
- TeamsTab.Read.All
- TeamsTab.ReadWrite.All
- User.Read
- User.ReadWrite.All

Am pulling my hair out ... and there's barely anything left!

Answer (score 4):

If you remove "Group.Create" permission completely and test, it should work.

Seems it doesn't like "Group.Create" with "Group.ReadWrite.All"

Comment: Tried and still have the issue, thanks for the recommendation nonetheless.

Comment: Ok, so this is the solution actually, thanks so much, I said it didn't work because I forgot to renew the token with the new permissions. Amazing you wrote this otherwise my app wouldn't work

Comment: lost hours when I finaly reached your solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If it works in Graph Explorer, but doesn't in Postman. That typically means that your access token in Postman is not correct.

Have you looked at the Postman collection I put together? It puts on rails fetching the access token based on your application id and secret. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman

With regards to PowerAutomate. How are you entering the application id and secret for the the flow to get the application access token? We do have a tutorial here from start to finish to show the approach we recommend here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/flow

Comment: We have been having this issue with multiple Office365 tenants. We reached out to Microsoft and they said it is a server-side bug from their side that they are fixing. They are deploying a fix for one of our customers now. This is not throttling as the error occurs from the first API call. Unfortunately, you can't do anything about it except opening a ticket to Microsoft. By the way, this call had been working fine for over a year. The error started occurring by the end of February 2020.

Comment: @Jeremy: We are having the exact same issue, I just sent two emails to Microsoft support and they said that although we pay Standard support (100$ per month) that doesn't include Development support and I need to either pay or come here to stackoverflow

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the entitlement issues with Microsoft Support and any Microsoft 365 Developer related ticket. I'm actually campaigning internally at the moment and have  a proposal i'm about to make to our EVP to fix this.

With regards to this 503 issue, it is indeed an error on the server side under the hood in Microsoft Graph. I have asked the SharePoint PM to look at this and get back to me. I'll update here. It essentially means that the SharePoint "farm" that your SharePoint Online instance is on is overloaded. But we're investigating why it impacted your calls.